# how to pass random numbers to a constructor java

Tags: java

```
instead of asking the user to input three numbers.
```

I wrote a for loop to generate 3 random numbers
 but I did not know how to pass the three numbers to the constructor.
 it is fine if anyone can use another way to pass a three random numbers
 to the constructor.

```
Random dice = new Random();

int[] numbers = null;

for (int counter = 1; counter < 4; counter++) {
    numbers[counter] = dice.nextInt(6) + 1;
}

ThreeDiceScorer player1 = new ThreeDiceScorer(x, x, x);
```

Comment: You're initializing the array to `null`, arrays indices are 0-based, and you can pass the array itself to the constructor after you initialize it properly.

Comment: If you only want 3 then it may make sense to extract the dice roll method and call it 3 times.

Comment: You provided the code from your attempt, and this is good, however your question will be better received on SO if you clearly write down the errors you get, from which line, and whether they are compilation error or exceptions during execution. This process will also help yourself understanding and debugging the errors !

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code, so first I would suggest reading some book about programming in Java, there are many good ones out there.

First thing that you need to do is initialize array.

So change line
 `int[] numbers = null;`
to
 `int[] numbers = new int[3];`

This will initialize int array of size 3, if you set array to null you will get `NullPointerException` when trying to access values inside array.

Now you need to change your for loop, arrays in Java start with index 0 not 1, so your loop should look like this:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
  numbers[counter] = dice.nextInt(6) + 1;
}
```

Now you can write:
`ThreeDiceScorer player1 = new ThreeDiceScorer(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]);`

Answer (score 0):

First initialize your array with 3 elements:

```
int[] numbers = new int[3];
```

Then grab your values and pass them to the constructor:

```
new ThreeDiceScorer(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]);
```